# How to vertically align <details>'s arrow with <summary>'s content

Tags: css, html

I am trying to vertically align the arrow that comes with the [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) element. As you can see in the demo below two things bother me:

1. the second line of the [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) doesn't start at the same horizontal position as the first line.
2. the `summary`'s text content isn't vertically aligned with the arrow.

```css
details {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu</summary>
  Nothing to see here.
</details>
```

**Current state**:

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

```css
summary {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div>
      Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu
    </div>
  </summary>
  Nothing to see here.
</details>
```

I have tried to wrap the summary content inside a div setting its property to `inline-block` but that only solved point **1**.

Answer (score 8):

You could implement your own foldable system. But the best way is to hack the `details` and `summary` elements a bit by removing the default arrow and placing a new one with the `:before` pseudo selector.

1. **start off by hiding the default arrow**:

   ```
   summary::-webkit-details-marker {
     display: none;
   }
   ```
2. then add your own arrows with the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property

   closed:

   ```
   summary:before {
     content: "►";
   }
   ```

   opened:

   ```
   details[open] summary:before {
     content: "▼";
   }
   ```
3. add a wrapping `div` element for our `summary`'s text:

   Now our structure looks like:

   ```
   <summary>
     ::before
     <div>
       Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu
     </div>
   </summary>
   ```
4. we need to align the `::before` element with the `div` element:

   - set some `width` and `margin` to `summary:before`
   - set `summary > div`'s `display` to `inline-block` to align the two blocks
   - let `summary > div` have the remaining horizontal space by using the CSS function  [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

     ```
     summary > div {
       width: calc(100% - 50px); /* 50px is the space taken by summary::before */
     }
     ```
   - to align the two blocks horizontally simply set `vertical-align` to `middle`

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}

summary > div {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

details {
  font-size: 20px;
}

summary {
  display: block
}

summary:before {
  content: "►";
  margin: 0px 10px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
}

details[open] summary:before {
  content: "▼";
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary><div>Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu</div></summary>
    <div>Nothing to see here.</div>
</details>
<br>
<details>
    <summary><div>This is actually an even bigger summary text, and it works! The arrow on the left is perfectly positioned. Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu</div></summary>
    <div>Nothing to see here.</div>
</details>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just a note, use `flex` instead of `inline-block`, it has more features.

Comment: @Vucko, is it really that useful to use `flex`? I personally never used it and while searching for other answers I found out I could just use `display: inline-block`. I don't actually know `flex`, what would it bring more?

Comment: you answer your qustion in moment you post it??

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes, I did, read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You can always answer your own question (there's a checkbox at the bottom of the question's editor reading: **`Answer your own question`**. As you can see the answer I gave myself isn't the unique answer: Temani Afif has an [easier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132030/6331369).

Comment: @לבנימלכה It's a common case when you face an issue and you found a solution so you prepare both of them and you post them at the same time to share what you found ;) Of course, other user can post more answer if they found more solutions

Comment: Of course...I know... Now I guess you want maybe more idea or shorter code and not answer to issue(because you have your own answer)

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice... I did not know that it possible(I mean in same moment)]

Comment: @לבנימלכה that's right, I am trying to get better answers (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132030/6331369) ;) ) and also save it so that other users in the future can find it if they are searching for the same thing as me.

Comment: fine have luck... :)

Comment: Nice. If you add `summary { display: block}` it'll work in Firefox too.

Answer (score 6):

You can also rely on flexbox and keep the default behavior:

```css
summary {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
summary > div {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div>
      Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu
    </div>
  </summary>
  Nothing to see here.
</details>
```

Comment: But the arrow disappeared. OP wants to align it to the arrow.

Comment: @Genom if you are using Firefox then yes, it's bug there .. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583004/html5-summary-element-with-some-text-right-justified/52583024#52583024

Comment: As of 2021, this does not work in Safari (arrow above the text), nor Firefox (no arrow visible at all). I have not tested other browsers.

Comment: The line "details[open] summary:before" should have > before summary to support nested details use.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap summary's text into `<div>`, limit it width to ~`calc(100% - 50px)` and set `vertical-align: middle`;

```css
summary {
  font-size: 30px;
}

summary > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary><div>Show more, you can click here on the summary's label to fold down the hidden menu</div></summary>
  Nothing to see here.
</details>
```

I have no idea why it's working but seems like it's ok for all browsers.