# html5 <summary> element with some text right justified

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use html5's `<details>` and `<summary>` elements 
to present a collapsible/expandable outline-style list but 
can't figure out how to get the `<summary>` element text formatted 
correctly.

I want the text left justified and the timestamp 
and block of links right justified.  I tried to do this by 
using a flexbox for the line and doing the layout inside the 
flexbox.  This works fine for the text in the `<details>` part.

However, on the summary line everything I've tried results in
either the text being properly formatted (like the details text)
but on a line below the triangle, or on the same line as the 
triangle, but with everything left justified.

Here is a snippet of showing the summary text formatted correctly
but on a new line.

```css
.outline { background-color: #e0e0ff; margin: 30px; }
      /* Styling on <details> and <summary> below provides
         indentation for nested details blocks. */
    details > *:not(summary) { margin-left: 1em; }
    summary { display: list-item; }
    .title { display: flex; }
    .bsect { display: flex; }
    .ttext, .ts, .actions, .btext { border: 1px solid green; }
    .ttext, .btext { flex: 1; }
    .ts, .actions  { flex: 0; white-space:nowrap; }
    pre  { white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0; font-size: 12pt }
```

```html
<div class="outline">
    <details id="b5750h35">
      <summary>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
          <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">L1</a>
            <a href="#">L2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </summary>
      <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
      <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect"><!--flex container-->
        <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
          </div>
        <!--more bsects or details go here -->
        </div><!--id="b5750c32"-->
      </details><!-- id="b5750h35" -->

    </div>
```

Changing the `.title { display: flex; }` to `.title { display: inline-flex; }` shows the other result (text on same line as triangle but everything left-justified; can gets the same result using `<spans>`s instead of `<div>`s):

```css
    .outline { background-color: #e0e0ff; margin: 30px; }
      /* Styling on <details> and <summary> below provides
         indentation for nested details blocks. */
    details > *:not(summary) { margin-left: 1em; }
    summary { display: list-item; }
    .title { display: inline-flex; }
    .bsect { display: flex; }
    .ttext, .ts, .actions, .btext { border: 1px solid green; }
    .ttext, .btext { flex: 1; }
    .ts, .actions  { flex: 0; white-space:nowrap; }
    pre  { white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0; font-size: 12pt }
```

```html
  <div class="outline">
    <details id="b5750h35">
      <summary>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
          <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">L1</a>
            <a href="#">L2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </summary>
      <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
      <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect"><!--flex container-->
        <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
          </div>
        <!--more bsects or details go here -->
        </div><!--id="b5750c32"-->
      </details><!-- id="b5750h35" -->

    </div>
```

What magic is needed to get the properly formatted text on the same 
line as the triangle?  I'd prefer a simple solution that continues 
to use flexbox if possible but if some other approach to achieving 
the wanted results is better, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* added this to center the arrow. optional */
}
summary .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.outline { background-color: #e0e0ff; margin: 30px; }
      /* Styling on <details> and <summary> below provides
         indentation for nested details blocks. */
    details > *:not(summary) { margin-left: 1em; }
    summary { display: list-item; }
    .title { display: inline-flex; }
    .bsect { display: flex; }
    .ttext, .ts, .actions, .btext { border: 1px solid green; }
    .ttext, .btext { flex: 1; }
    .ts, .actions  { flex: 0; white-space:nowrap; }
    pre  { white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0; font-size: 12pt }
    
summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
summary .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline">
    <details id="b5750h35">
      <summary>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
          <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">L1</a>
            <a href="#">L2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </summary>
      <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
      <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect"><!--flex container-->
        <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
          </div>
        <!--more bsects or details go here -->
        </div><!--id="b5750c32"-->
      </details><!-- id="b5750h35" -->

    </div>
```

---

As alohci pointed out, in FF the arrow is not displayed unless summary has `display:list-item`.

One way to make it work with `display:list-item` is using floats:

```
.title, .bsect {
   width: calc(100% - 1.08em);
   float: right;
}
details {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.outline { background-color: #e0e0ff; margin: 30px; }
      /* Styling on <details> and <summary> below provides
         indentation for nested details blocks. */
    details > *:not(summary) { margin-left: 1em; }
    summary { display: list-item; }
    .title { display: inline-flex; }
    .bsect { display: flex; }
    .ttext, .ts, .actions, .btext { border: 1px solid green; }
    .ttext, .btext { flex: 1; }
    .ts, .actions  { flex: 0; white-space:nowrap; }
    pre  { white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0; font-size: 12pt }
    
.title, .bsect {
   width: calc(100% - 1.08em);
   float: right;
}
details {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline">
    <details id="b5750h35">
      <summary>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
          <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">L1</a>
            <a href="#">L2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </summary>
      <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
      <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect"><!--flex container-->
        <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
          </div>
        <!--more bsects or details go here -->
        </div><!--id="b5750c32"-->
      </details><!-- id="b5750h35" -->

    </div>
```

Not as neat and clean as flexbox, but does work.

Comment: in the first snippet he's using this and the result is not what he wanted

Comment: You were right, @TemaniAfif. ^^. But, out of principle, I don't agree with `flex:1`. It sets 3 properties and people don't understand it. It's less helpful for them (increases confusion around flexbox).

Comment: Thanks but this has same issue as @temani-afif solution, it loses the triangle that shows if the item is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: @yama: You mean you don't see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGzPO.png)? What browser are you using?

Comment: Correct, the title text, "A short..." and its border, are right up against the left edge of the grey background.  The grey background does not extend to the left with the triangle as your image shows.   Using Firefox-62.0.  When I tried Chrome-69.0.3497.100, the results look like your image with the triangle present.

Comment: @yama, I added an alternative solution, using `float`. Not "better", but working.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it answers my question as stated. Unfortunately my question was too narrow and when I try making the 'Lx' links more complicated
(eg dropdown menu) I am running into problems I think due to the "float"
(which is what I'd hoped to avoid by using flexbox.)   Thanks again for the answers.

Comment: @yama, feel free to ask a new question. Off the bat, I can tell you dropdowns are pretty complex UI elements and making them work cross-browser, cross-device, for all cases, is often impossible without javascript (DOM manipulation). Reasons ranging from differences in how they behave, display and get aligned on each type of device to having to overflow parents without overflow. In short, people tend to expect different behavior from dd's than from normal content, which makes them special, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

Make the summary a flex container then add `flex:1` to `.title` to make it fit all the space:

```css
.outline { background-color: #e0e0ff; margin: 30px; }
      /* Styling on <details> and <summary> below provides
         indentation for nested details blocks. */
    details > *:not(summary) { margin-left: 1em; }
    .title { display: flex; }
    .bsect { display: flex; }
    .ttext, .ts, .actions, .btext { border: 1px solid green; }
    .ttext, .btext { flex: 1; }
    .ts, .actions  { flex: 0; white-space:nowrap; }
    pre  { white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0; font-size: 12pt }
    
 summary {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
 }
 summary > .title {
  flex:1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outline">
    <details id="b5750h35">
      <summary>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
          <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">L1</a>
            <a href="#">L2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </summary>
      <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
      <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect"><!--flex container-->
        <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
          </div>
        <!--more bsects or details go here -->
        </div><!--id="b5750c32"-->
      </details><!-- id="b5750h35" -->

    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

For Firefox you can consider adding width to the `inline-flex` element. We can consider `em` unit to make it working with any `font-size`:

```css
.outline {
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
  margin: 30px;
}

details>*:not(summary) {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.title {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.bsect {
  display: flex;
}

.ttext,
.ts,
.actions,
.btext {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.ttext,
.btext {
  flex: 1;
}

.ts,
.actions {
  flex: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12pt
}

summary>.title {
  width: calc(100% - 1.1em);
  margin-left: -0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline">
  <details id="b5750h35">
    <summary>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </summary>
    <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
    <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect">
      <!--flex container-->
      <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
      <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="#">L1</a>
        <a href="#">L2</a>
      </div>
      <!--more bsects or details go here -->
    </div>
    <!--id="b5750c32"-->
  </details>
  <!-- id="b5750h35" -->

</div>

<div class="outline" style="font-size:25px;">
  <details id="b5750h35">
    <summary>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="ttext">A short title </div>
        <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#">L1</a>
          <a href="#">L2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </summary>
    <!-- Following the summary are zero or more intermixed
           bsect and detail blocks -->
    <div id="b5750c32" class="bsect">
      <!--flex container-->
      <pre class="btext">Some multi-line
 body text.</pre>
      <div class="ts">2018-07-05 12:00</div>
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="#">L1</a>
        <a href="#">L2</a>
      </div>
      <!--more bsects or details go here -->
    </div>
    <!--id="b5750c32"-->
  </details>
  <!-- id="b5750h35" -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that loses the triangle that shows if the item is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: One of the big problems with display/summary is that Gecko chose to implement it in a completely different way to Blink. Gecko reuses `display:list-item` to display the marker, so using any other display value removes the marker control.

Comment: @yamagoya my bad .. didn't test on FF, will try to find another way

Comment: OK, now that I know what to google for, I see a lot of
info on Firefox's disappearing <summary> arrow.  So the 
<summary> element must retain display:list-item and cant 
be changed to display:flex.

I still don't get why my snippet #2 above doesn't work.
From reading on MDN the "inline-flex" in the .title div
means the containing summary element should treat it as 
inline (which seems to be true as it is not placed on a 
new line) but inside the .title div it should be a regular 
flexbox container in which the normal flex layout rules apply.  
Why isn't that part happening?

Comment: @yamagoya yes but inline means *fit the content* so inline-flex will behave like inline-block and inline-grid, they will shrink to fit their content. An easy fix is to add a width to the inline-flex item consider the width of the arrow: Check the update of my answer

Comment: This had a problem for me: the horizontal position of the fields floated right
vary according to browser.  On Chrome, the timestamp fields are almost aligned (off 
only a few pixels) between the summary and details rows but on Firefox are off a lot 
more.  The 0.3px setting can adjust this but obviously one doesn't want to tune per browser.  Thanks again for the answers.

Comment: Fair play on using `em` when reducing `width` there.